# Optimally fit different sized cards on a paper (from interview)

Tags: java, c++, dynamic-programming

I saw this interesting interview question on glassdoor, but I couldn't find the solution.

Lets assume I have a paper in the size of 8" by 11". How would I go about designing an algorithm that optimally fit smaller cards onto the paper.

Now I don't have the actual card dimensions but for this example lets assume the smaller cards are 3" by 4", 7" by 2" and 5" by 3".

I understand that this is a packing problem, but I wanted to know how to use dynamic programming to get a faster solution than brute force and handle the rotation at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably think of these following algorithms as they have time complexity O(n log n) :

1. First-Fit Decreasing Height (FFDH) algorithm
2. Next-Fit Decreasing Height (NFDH) algorithm
3. Hybrid First-Fit (HFF)
4. Hybrid Next-Fit (HNF)